# Refering to type parameter of enclosing type

Tags: scala, scope, type-parameter

Is it possible to refer to an outer scope type parameter from an inner scope where a type with the same name is declared?

For instance, **Addable**s *A* needs to be refined in a scope where a type A is already defined:

```
trait Addable {
  type A
  def addTwo(x: A, y: A): A
}

implicit class GenericAddable[A](first: A) {
  def +(second: A)(implicit proxy: Addable { type A = ??? }) =
    proxy.addTwo(first, second)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's not possible. Use a different name for the type parameter of `GenericAddable` instead.

Or, alternatively, define a private alias of a different name:

```
implicit class GenericAddable[A](first: A) {
  private type OuterA = A
  def +(second: A)(implicit proxy: Addable { type A = OuterA }) =
    proxy.addTwo(first, second)
}
```

Comment: That's almost letter-for-letter identical to what I ended up with :)